# Speed up oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a query which I am trying to optimize a query which is taking 6 minutes to run (DS1 has 200k rows and DS2 200k rows as well). I was wondering if there is any optimizations that a oracle guru can see?
I am by no means an expert more of a hobbyist...the problem looks like the grouping part is taking the longest to do...

```
WITH DS1 AS
  (SELECT
    /*+ PARALLEL */
    *
  FROM PD1
  WHERE TYPE      = 'TSY'
  AND SOURCE = 'A'
  ),
  DS2 AS
  (SELECT
    /*+ PARALLEL */
    *
  FROM PD1
  WHERE TYPE     = 'LGL'
  AND SOURCE = 'B'
  ),
  Q AS
  (SELECT DS1.ID  AS DS1_ID,
    DS1.CODE  AS DS1_CODE,
    DS2.CODE  AS DS2_CODE,
    DS2.ID        AS DS2_ID,
    DS1.TYPE        AS TYPE1,
    DS2.TYPE        AS TYPE2,
    DS1.SOURCE AS SS1,
    DS2.SOURCE AS SS2,
    DS1.ATTRIBUTE,
    DS1.ATTRIBUTE_VAL,
    DS1.ATT_AND_VAL
  FROM DS1
  JOIN DS2
  ON DS1.ATT_AND_VAL = DS2.ATT_AND_VAL
  ) ,
  GROUPINGS AS
  (SELECT
    /*+no_merge */
    DS1_ID                  AS BASE_ID ,
    DS1_CODE               AS BASE_CODE,
    DS2_CODE               AS TARGET_CODE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(DS2_ID)) AS COUNT_OF_TARGET_ID
  FROM Q
  GROUP BY DS1_ID,
    DS1_CODE,
    DS2_CODE
  )
SELECT *
FROM GROUPINGS
ORDER BY BASE_ID,
  BASE_CODE,
  TARGET_CODE;
```

Comment: The first thing to do is examine the explain plan. Please get the explain plan output (as text, not an image) and include it with your question.

Comment: Also, what's the primary/unique key on the PD1 table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be tempted to just simplify the existing query by removing all the common table expressions and hints. Like this:

```
SELECT
    DS1_ID                     AS BASE_ID
  , DS1_CODE                   AS BASE_CODE
  , DS2_CODE                   AS TARGET_CODE
  , COUNT( DISTINCT (DS2_ID) ) AS COUNT_OF_TARGET_ID
FROM (
    SELECT
        DS1.ID     AS DS1_ID
      , DS1.CODE   AS DS1_CODE
      , DS2.CODE   AS DS2_CODE
      , DS2.ID     AS DS2_ID
    FROM PD1 DS1
    JOIN PD1 DS2 ON DS1.ATT_AND_VAL = DS2.ATT_AND_VAL
                AND DS2.TYPE = 'LGL'
                AND DS2.SOURCE = 'B'
    WHERE DS1.TYPE = 'TSY'
    AND DS1.SOURCE = 'A'
    ) Q
GROUP BY
    DS1_ID
  , DS1_CODE
  , DS2_CODE
ORDER BY
    BASE_ID
  , BASE_CODE
  , TARGET_CODE
;
```

If this is taking minutes to run then I would suggest you need to add indexes. The first thing to do is get an explain plan to determine if any indexes are being used to narrow down the next steps.